# Vim -- Mapping of <c-<> not working?

Tags: vim

I want to map `c-<` to be `<c-w> <`, so I put these in my .vimrc:

```
noremap <c-<> <c-w><
```

And it doesn't work.

`:verbose map <c-<>` shows:

```
<C-<>       * <C-W><
```

Which means the mapping has succeeded.

If I try `noremap <c-.> <c-w><`, it doesn't work either; but if I try `noremap <c-e> <c-w><`, it actually works.

I don't understand.. does vim disallow  kind of mapping>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to find different keys for your mapping - those won't work.**

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.